# How do I add a pin to my Google Map from Google Developers Tutorial

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been using the Google Developers Tutorial on how to add a map to my website:

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map#the_finished_code

I cannot seem to find a way to add a pin to the map, I have used the "centre" function so that the map is centred on the lat and long of the pin, but the pin itself is not visible.

Any way to create a pin at that lat and long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to instantiate a marker Object and place it at the coordinates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var myLatLng = {lat: 44.5403, lng: -78.5463};
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
  });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/byLwz79q/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have used:

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: (51.434408, -2.53531),
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
  });

In the relevant place, however nothing is appearing!

Comment: Hi there. Chances are you are missing a closing bracket or something somewhere. See the Fiddle for a working example using the script above. I did a couple things other than just adding the marker script - check close, I set up some variables and such as well. First, check your console for errors.

Comment: Thank you again, you were right I forgot to actually add the Var for LatLan! Got a working marker now!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

replace `center` with `location`

before:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng),
```

after:

```
location: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatLng),
```

That should do the trick (should add the Pin automatically).